# scp transfer file through the terminal to a linux server

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, file-transfer, scp

I have connected to linux server through the terminal windows on my Mac via ssh
now I am trying to transfer file through scp but I get an error:

```
[egb@csl3 ~]$ scp /Users/home/Desktop/part1.c egb@csl3.cs.tech.ac.il:~egb/mtm/ex0/part1

The authenticity of host 'csl3.cs.tech.ac.il (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.

ECDSA key fingerprint is
ECDSA key fingerprint is 
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'csl3.cs.tech.ac.il' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
egb@csl3.cs.tech.ac.il's password: 
/Users/home/Desktop/part1.c: No such file or directory
```

What's did I do wrong?
I got the location of the file I want to transfer by dragging it inside the terminal window as I read in many other articles

Comment: Is your Desktop really in `/Users/home/` ? Your username seems to be "egb", so it would normally be `/Users/egb/Desktop`. You could also try just `scp Desktop/` and use the Tab key to complete the name of your source file.

Comment: First try `ssh egb@csl3.cs.tech.ac.il`. When that is worked out, try the scp command.